# Aforge Image Rotation results in a red X

Tags: c#, aforge

I am trying to rotate an image using AForge. Here is the code (in the paint event method for a picture box):

```
int radius = 10; 
Image img = new Bitmap("file_path.png");
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(img, radius, radius);

//arbitrary angle of 67
RotateBilinear ro = new RotateBilinear(67, true);
image = ro.Apply(image);
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
g.DrawImage(image, 100, 100);
```

If I take out the RotateBilinear line and the ro.Apply line it draws the original image just fine but when i try to rotate it, the background of the form turns white and a red x with an outline of red around the form appears. Anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a try/catch around your code.

```
int radius = 10; 
Image img = new Bitmap("file_path.png");
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(img, radius, radius);
//arbitrary angle of 67

try
{
    image = AForge.Imaging.Image.Clone(image, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    RotateBilinear ro = new RotateBilinear(67, true);
    image = ro.Apply(image);
}
catch (Exception e)
{ 
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Caught Exception {0}\n{1}", e.GetType(), e.Message);
} 

Graphics g = e.Graphics;
g.DrawImage(image, 100, 100);
```

If my suspicions are right, you will have the red x disappear, the image will be rendered un-rotated. AND you will have some trace statements in you output window in Visual Studio telling you the Exception Type and the Exception Message. That information should give you some idea of what it is that is going wrong.

Comment: I received the error message-> "Source pixel format is not supported by the filter". Not sure what I need to change about my png to make it work.

Comment: Doing a quick google suggests that you might have to create an image with the proper PixelFormat option. I've added the appropriate code inside the try clause - never having used the AForge library I cannot vouch for the exact PixelFormat enumerator to use, but you should be able to find out which one you can use by looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You get the red X when the code generates an exception fault.

I don't see where you have allocated `agent` or `argent.image`, yet you make use of these variables/properties. I suspect you have some null values or similar in there and that you really meant to write:

```
image = ro.Apply(image);
```

because you set up `image` initially and use it in the `DrawImage` call.

Comment: I actually wrote it wrong on here but I fixed it, I do use the image i setup in this method but it still doesn't work.